# is there a video codec that can be loaded by Flash and Silverlight seamlessly?

Tags: flash, silverlight, actionscript-3, video, streaming

is there any possibility for loading flv or f4v on silverlight platform?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Flash Player 10 supports**:

H.264, Screen Video, Screen Video 2, Sorenson Spark, On 2 VP6 in mp4, flv, and f4v.

**Silverlight supports**:

Windows Media Video 7-9, and H.264 in wmv, asx, and mp4.

*Looks like H.264 in mp4 is the one.*

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please mark as your accepted answer, otherwise let me know where you need clarification and I'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 1):

H.264 mp4 works with both platforms. I'm sure there are others.